# Export Ionic project from Ionic Creator using Ionic CLI option

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I am new to Ionic framework .

Actally I have seen this option of ionic CLI for exporting the project from ionic creator in below video

[Ionic Creator Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=11&v=CBsBKRriZFI)

But I can not see this option in my project in both the version of ionic latest and oldest.

Can you please help me to find out this

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
bhumika

Comment: wow i didn't know that was such a thing like ionic creator. I always build form scratch

Comment: you can't see the option for exporting? that what I'm understanding from your question. if you post a screenshot of your screen would be helpful for us

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the ionic creator provides some extra features to the templates apart from what you can download using the IONIC CLI.

If you are not able to download the project the way you described, try the following

```
-$ ionic start myNewProject
```

For the above command you get a response like below

```
    What starter would you like to use: (Use arrow keys)
❯ tabs ............... ionic-angular A starting project with a simple tabbed int
erface 
  blank .............. ionic-angular A blank starter project 
  sidemenu ........... ionic-angular A starting project with a side menu with na
vigation in the content area 
  super .............. ionic-angular A starting project complete with pre-built 
pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development. 
  conference ......... ionic-angular A project that demonstrates a realworld app
lication 
  tutorial ........... ionic-angular A tutorial based project that goes along wi
th the Ionic documentation 
  aws ................ ionic-angular AWS Mobile Hub Starter
```

You can choose a template and get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your project by clicking export in ionic creator and it will download with .zip file, you can extract it and put it in new file www. Then, create new blank app and copy templates you exported from ionic creator and put it in your new blank app in src and www and then test it with command:

```
ionic serve
```